# Hide overflow centered text in HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

I am having trouble setting up an affect from a HTML that contains one row with centered text that overflows the width of the row.  Below is an example of what I have tried and I get the hidden text but only on the right side of the row.  Can someone please let me know if this is possible?

```
    <div id="div1" style="display:inline; position: absolute; top:108px; left: 28px; width:403px; height:74px; background-color:transparent; z-index: 2; border: solid 0px #000000; color: #000000; ">
      <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="color: #000000; font-family: Microsoft Sans Serif; font-size: 8.25pt; table-layout:fixed; ">
          <tr>
              <td id="tsp1" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><div style="height:100%; text-align:center; overflow:hidden;">This is a test of the text subpanel wrapping capabilities or lack there of in the thick client versus the web client.</div></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a **"dirty"** method to do it:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Example</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function setCentered()
    {
        currString=$("#target").text();
        if(currString.length>16)
        {
            //magic equation
            amount=(currString.length-16);
            $("#target").css("margin-left","-"+amount.toString()+"px");
        }
    }
    // -->
</script>
<head>
<body onLoad="javascript:setCentered()">
    <div id="div1" style=" display:inline; position: absolute; top:108px; left: 28px; width:80px; height:74px; background-color:transparent; z-index: 2; border: solid 2px red; color: #000000; ">
        <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="color: #000000; font-family: Microsoft Sans Serif; font-size: 8.25pt; table-layout:fixed; ">
            <tr>
                <td id="tsp1" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:center; overflow:hidden;"><p id="target">Space test #122 of totalling.</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Remember that you have to **improve** the magic equation in the js-code considering the *various* font and display settings.

Comment: Thanks Gino, now the problem that exists is I need the ability to have this work with left, right and center justifications.  Plus, I could have one or more tables with what would be different paragraph tag id's, which would have to be taken into account for the javascript.  Any ideas?  thanks

Comment: 1. Regarding the justifications, manage them in the equation: for example you can do a switch-case, behaving in a different way for each different justification. In the right-jus case, do not enter in the if unless the text has reached the left-side of the td-tag.

Comment: 2. Regarding the table id's, in jQuery you can traverse each table of the entire page using the each() function, regardless of the id-tags. Plus, you can add, always through jQuery, a special class-tag to each td-element of the page (in run-time, jQuery) and use it to identificate your td's tag in the js-code. ( .addClass() )